# v-for stuck on index [0] = how do I loop through data correctly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Hi I'm struggling to loop through my data, I have gone through various methods as per vue doc's but it appears to only loop the once and I cannot see where i am going wrong, ant help appreciated.

home.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <Header />

    <div v-if="images">    
      
      <div  v-for="image in images" :key="image.href" class="image-div">
        <ImageWindow :href="image.href" /> <!--pass href as props to component -->
        
        <p>{{image.href}}</p> <!-- Error Check -->
        {{image}}<!-- This renders the whole data array-->
      </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>

import Header from '@/components/Header.vue'
import ImageWindow from '@/components/ImageWindow.vue'


export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    Header,
    ImageWindow
  },
  computed: {
    images: function(){
      return this.$store.state.images
    }
  }

</script>
```

the data looks like this:

```
[ { "render": "image", "rel": "preview", "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA12274/PIA12274~thumb.jpg" }, 
{ "render": "image", "rel": "preview", "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA02348/PIA02348~thumb.jpg" }, 
{ "render": "image", "rel": "preview", "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/GSFC_20171208_Archive_e000590/GSFC_20171208_Archive_e000590~thumb.jpg" }, 
{ "render": "image", "rel": "preview", "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-20170120-PH_AAG01_0001/KSC-20170120-PH_AAG01_0001~thumb.jpg" }, 
{ "render": "image", "rel": "preview", "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA17979/PIA17979~thumb.jpg" }, 
{ "render": "image", "rel": "preview", "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA17789/PIA17789~thumb.jpg" }, 
{ "render": "image", "rel": "preview", "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA21885/PIA21885~thumb.jpg" }, 
{ "render": "image", "rel": "preview", "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA12443/PIA12443~thumb.jpg" }, 
{ "render": "image", "rel": "preview", "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA07478/PIA07478~thumb.jpg" }]
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end this was my error. checking vue dev tools I had in fact nested an array in an array, so to access this I needed to change images to images[0].

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Just add data() in vue [for more info](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods)

correct code

```
let vue = new Vue({
    el: ".home",
    // the data() you forget
  data(){
    return {images: [ 
    { "render": "image", "rel": "preview", "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA12274/PIA12274~thumb.jpg" }, 
    { "render": "image", "rel": "preview", "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA02348/PIA02348~thumb.jpg" }, 
    { "render": "image", "rel": "preview", "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/GSFC_20171208_Archive_e000590/GSFC_20171208_Archive_e000590~thumb.jpg" }, 
    { "render": "image", "rel": "preview", "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-20170120-PH_AAG01_0001/KSC-20170120-PH_AAG01_0001~thumb.jpg" }, 
    { "render": "image", "rel": "preview", "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA17979/PIA17979~thumb.jpg" }, 
    { "render": "image", "rel": "preview", "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA17789/PIA17789~thumb.jpg" }, 
    { "render": "image", "rel": "preview", "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA21885/PIA21885~thumb.jpg" }, 
    { "render": "image", "rel": "preview", "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA12443/PIA12443~thumb.jpg" }, 
    { "render": "image", "rel": "preview", "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA07478/PIA07478~thumb.jpg" }
    ]}
  }
})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

 <div class="home">
    <div v-if="images">    
      
      <div  v-for="image in images" :key="image.href" class="image-div">
        <p>{{image.href}}</p> <!-- Error Check -->
        {{image}}<!-- This renders the whole data array-->
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you mean to post this? i cant see anything changed?